# Dimension of spaces of invariants/tableaux functions

Tags: young-tableaux, reference-request, ag.algebraic-geometry, invariant-theory, rt.representation-theory

The Hook lenght formula gives the number of standard Young tableaux on a given diagram.

A variant gives the number of semistandard tableuax.

Does there exist a formula for counting "weighted tableaux"? By weighted tableaux I mean that there exists a vector $(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ and I only want to count the tableaux with entries in $\{1,\dots,n\}$ such that $i$ appears exactly $a_i$ times.

Does anybody have a reference for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The numbers you refer to are known as Kostka numbers.  They are discussed in standard references like Fulton's Young Tableaux and Stanley's Enumerative Combinatorics.  The weights of a tableaux are often referred to as their content, as well.

Comment: What is the number for the partition $2n=(2,2,2,...,2)$ and $a_i=2$ for all $i$ ?

Comment: sorry, just ignore the last comment. I need the number for the partition $2n=(n,n)$ and $a_i=2$ for all $i=1,2, \cdots ,n$.